# can we use aggregate functions in insert query with more than one column values?

Tags: sql-server

My query is

```
insert into student 
values('pravin', 1990-08-06, 'hyderabad', select count(*) from student, 'male', 1990-5-3, 1989-4-6)
```

and I'm getting an error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near 'male'.

And

```
insert into student 
values('pravin', 1990-08-06, select min(location) from student, 5645645646, 'male', 1990-5-3, 1989-4-6)
```

results in:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '5645645646'.

Table structure -

```
create table student
(
      StudentId int identity
      ,StudentName varchar(50)
      ,[Date Of Birth] datetime
      ,Location varchar(50)
      ,ContactNo varchar(50)
      ,Gender varchar(50)
      ,[Date Created] datetime
      ,[Date Modified] datetime
 )
```

SAMPLE INSERT STATEMENTS-

```
insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified])
values('pravin',1990-08-06,'hyderabad',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)
 
insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('John',1990-08-06,'chennai',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)

inse‌​rt into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('Krish',1990-08-06,'banglore',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)
```

Comment: Pravin, @marc_s has explained you all the possibilities, please try to understand the code and example, show your table structure. What is the data type of location column and also show sample data.

Comment: create table student(StudentId int identity,StudentName varchar(50), [Date Of Birth] datetime, Location varchar(50), ContactNo varchar(50), Gender varchar(50), [Date Created] datetime, [Date Modified] datetime)

Comment: sample data........................insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('pravin',1990-08-06,'hyderabad',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)
------------------insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('John',1990-08-06,'chennai',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)-----insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('Krish',1990-08-06,'banglore',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)

Answer (score 5):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to explain that you **cannot** use a `SELECT` in the middle of a list of `VALUES()` in an `INSERT` statement - you'll need to use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ....` style, so instead of this:

```
insert into student 
values('pravin', 1990-08-06, 'hyderabad', select count(*) from student, 'male', 1990-5-3, 1989-4-6)
```

you will need to use this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Student(provide-the-list-of-columns-here!)
   SELECT
      'pravin', '19900806', 'hyderabad', 
      COUNT(*) 
      'male', '19900503', '19890406'
  FROM 
      dbo.student
```

Notes:

- **always** provide the **list of columns** you're inserting into in your `INSERT` statement
- put your dates into single quotes!
- also, I recommend to always use the ISO-8601 format - `YYYYMMDD` - which is the one format that works regardless of your language and dateformat settings

**UPDATE #2:**

You commented with this code:

```
insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('pravin',1990-08-06,select max(location) from student,5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6) –
```

And again: **no**; you cannot do this! Sure it's not working - that what I've been trying to tell you all along!

If you want to use `SELECT MAX(Location) ....` in the middle of your `INSERT`, you **MUST** use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` style:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.student(StudentName, [Date Of Birth], Location, ContactNo, Gender, [Date Created], [Date Modified]) 
    SELECT
       'pravin', '19900806',
       MAX(location) 
       5645645646, 'male', '19900503', '19890406'
    FROM 
       dbo.student
```

And again: put **ALL** your dates into single quotes, and use the `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes!) format.

Comment: sorry, but my question is different. i.e I want to use aggregate function in SELECT query and that SELECT query in INSERT statement as column value.

Comment: @pravindamkondwar: I was trying to explain that you have to choose - either have all the values ready in variables - then use the `VALUES()` keyword. **OTHERWISE** you need to use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ....` approach.

Comment: actually, i used 1st column as identity column, so it will be automatically gets stored. and its optional to specify column names when we are passing all column values. so, i did not specify column names.

Comment: @pravindamkondwar: yes, it's *optional* - but **HIGHLY** recommended! Especially if you have an `IDENTITY` column in play - then you **MUST** specify the list of all the other columns you want to insert into. Just get into the habit of specifying the column names - it'll save you a lot of grief and trouble down the road! Trust me from 30+ years of experiences.....

Comment: This is also not working---------insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('pravin',1990-08-06,select max(location) from student,5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)

Comment: This query---- INSERT INTO dbo.student(StudentName, [Date Of Birth], Location, ContactNo, Gender, [Date Created], [Date Modified]) 
    SELECT
       'pravin', '19900806',
       MAX(location) 
       5645645646, 'male', '19900503', '19890406'
    FROM 
       dbo.student----------------------    GIving an error like this.........Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '5645645646'.

Comment: @pravindamkondwar - Kindly share your table design and sample data, just displaying errors on the screen will not help you. we will create a demo for you and show you how it works.

Comment: @Murtaza....create table student(StudentId int identity,StudentName varchar(50), [Date Of Birth] datetime, Location varchar(50), ContactNo varchar(50), Gender varchar(50), [Date Created] datetime, [Date Modified] datetime)                      ------------------

Comment: @Murtaza.....sample data............insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('pravin',1990-08-06,'hyderabad',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)
------------------insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('John',1990-08-06,'chennai',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)-----insert into student(StudentName,[Date Of Birth],Location,ContactNo,Gender,[Date Created],[Date Modified]) 
values('Krish',1990-08-06,'banglore',5645645646,'male',1990-5-3,1989-4-6)

Comment: @pravindamkondwar: please **DO NOT** post sample code or sample data into comments!! It's really hard to read - please instead **UPDATE** your original question by editing it!!