# insert a new record into a mysql table with one of the values incremented by 1

Tags: mysql

I've got the following table:

```
productId     price
1             price_value1
2             price_value2
3             price_value3
```

I would like to insert a new product into the table and assign it a new productId. In this case its value equals to 4. 
So I want my new table to look like so:

```
productId    price
1            price_value1
2            price_value2
3            price_value3
4            price_value4
```

So as far as I understand, in order to do that I have to somehow retrieve the max value of productId and insert it using `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (productId + 1, price_value4)`.
But how do I find out the maximum value of productId?
I tried `INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (SELECT MAX(productId) + 1 FROM mytable, price_value4)` but  it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should Work:

Select the max(productID) and price_value4 as a columns from mytable and insert the result.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (SELECT MAX(productId) + 1, 'price_value4' FROM mytable);
```

However, if you are not going to jump some number you can just add an auto increment id key to product_id and then you will have only to insert the price, the product ID will be incremented automatically..
This will do so :

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
MODIFY COLUMN `productId` INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

you can change INT(10) with the INT(5) for example depanding on the size you want to give to your productId column

**EDIT :**

In return to the OP question in comments why his solution wouldn't work
Some suggetions says you have to make the SELECT statment in insert always between parenthesis

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM mytable) , price_value4)
```

.. In my Case it Return

> (1093): You can't specify target table
>   'mytable' for update in FROM clause

[**AND HERE IS WHY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) (Quoting From the documentation)

> When selecting from and inserting into the same table, MySQL creates
>   an internal temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then
>   inserts those rows into the target table. However, you cannot use
>   INSERT INTO t ... SELECT ... FROM t when t is a TEMPORARY table,
>   because TEMPORARY tables cannot be referred to twice in the same
>   statement

**BUT** there is  away to overcome by using a query instead of the table itself in the FROM, which has the effect of copying the requested table values instead of referencing the one that you are updating..

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( 
   (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable ) as mytmp ), 
   'price_value4');
```

OR (Quoting From the documentation)

> To avoid ambiguous column reference problems when the SELECT and the
>   INSERT refer to the same table, provide a unique alias for each table
>   used in the SELECT part, and qualify column names in that part with
>   the appropriate alias.

```
INSERT INTO mytable Values ( (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM mytable as mytmp) , 'price_value4')
```

Comment: I don't understand this part `price_value4 FROM mytable`, price_value4 is not in the table. And it yields a syntax error.

Comment: `price_value4` is a price that you want to insert so basically it is a value like `5 or 6..` whatever or a word `price_value4, price_value5...` in all ways it is like writing `select productID, '5' from mytable` it will not return any syntax error

Comment: hmm strange but it does return a syntax error. Seems like it's relevant, I'm using MariaDB. Does it change anything? I don't understand the point of 'FROM mytable' following price_value4. Would you please explain it?

Comment: nah in my case i'm not allowed to alter the table this way, so I would like to go with the first option but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @codeFish give me an example of a row you want to insert; what price_value4 should be for the productId 4? a specific number or word !.

Comment: Well for the sake of certainty, let's make it 1000.0.

Comment: `INSERT INTO mytable (SELECT MAX(productId) + 1, '1000' FROM mytable);` Excute  this and tell me what it return for you ?

Comment: Aah now it worked! The previous failures were due to a type that i managed to make a few times. Sorry. Thank you!

Comment: @codeFish Glad it helps.. For your previous question I am still searching I will make and Edit explaining why your code didn't work as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question. In order to take advantage of the auto-incrementing capability of the column, do not supply a value for that column when inserting rows. 
A simple syntax to create table

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
     productId MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     price INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (productid)
);
```

While inserting supplied default or leave column as blank or supplied value as NULL. Take a look at below code snippet.

```
INSERT INTO Product (price) VALUES
    ('10'),('20'),('4'),
    ('30');
```

[refer this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: the thing is that the table is already created. I cannot create it.

Comment: try this one. 
INSERT INTO Product(productId, price) 
    SELECT
       MAX(productId) + 1, pricevalue
    FROM 
      Product

Comment: refer this link, might you get your answer. I don't have MySQL installed on my local. I didn't try, let me know if does it work for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615897/can-we-use-aggregate-functions-in-insert-query-with-more-than-one-column-values